# How to use MIN, IFF and Datepart functions together in MS ACCESS?

Tags: sql, ms-access, datepart

I have a table like below, I want to group date time entries based on date without time and shifts for example, morning shift starts at 5 AM and ends at 14 PM. Here, MAX function finds the correct date, could you help me to see what's wrong with MIN function?

```
    Indate                Incondition
    ---------             -----------
    25.01.2013 05:00:38    KT-RING
    25.01.2013 05:21:52    KT-EMPTY
    25.01.2013 05:22:00    KT-PROCESS
    25.01.2013 06:10:50    KT-RING
    25.01.2013 16:10:50    KT-EMPTY
    26.01.2013 06:10:50    KT-RING

    SELECT  Int(Indate) AS DATE,  
    Min( IIf( ( DatePart('h',[Indate])>=05 AND DatePart('h', [Indate])<13), Indate, 0)) AS FRUHRINGMIN,
    Max(IIf((DatePart('h',Indate)>=05 And
    DatePart('h',Indate)<13), Indate,0)) AS FRUHRINGMAX 
FROM  TABLE WHERE Incondition= 'KT-RING' 
    GROUP BY Int(Indate);

    RESULT:
    DATE      FRUHRINGMIN     FRUHRINGMAX
    -----     -------------   -----------
   25.01.2013  00:00:00       25.01.2013 06:10:50 
   26.01.2013  00:00:00       26.01.2013 06:10:50
```

Answer (score 2):

I saved your sample data in a table in my Access 2007 database.  But when I attempted to run your query, Access threw an error about the alias `DATE`, which is a reserved word.  Bracketing that alias allowed the query to run without error.

```
SELECT
    Int(Indate) AS [DATE],  
    Min(IIf((DatePart('h',[Indate])>=05 AND DatePart('h', [Indate])<13), Indate, 0)) AS FRUHRINGMIN,
    Max(IIf((DatePart('h',Indate)>=05 And DatePart('h',Indate)<13), Indate,0)) AS FRUHRINGMAX 
FROM tblJeanneQuadel
WHERE Incondition= 'KT-RING' 
GROUP BY Int(Indate);
```

However the results it gave me did not match what you reported.

```
DATE  FRUHRINGMIN           FRUHRINGMAX
41299 1/25/2013 5:00:38 AM  1/25/2013 6:10:50 AM
41300 1/26/2013 6:10:50 AM  1/26/2013 6:10:50 AM
```

Note my Date/Time values are in US format, but they're actually based on the same values as yours, just displayed differently.

I don't understand why your query result displayed the first column as a date rather than a long integer as mine did and which I would expect as the result from `Int(Indate)`.  But that's a minor point; we can convert from one to the other if needed.

More importantly, I'm unsure about what's actually going on.  If bracketing `[DATE]` does not allow your query to run and produce the correct results, try moving the `IIf()` condition into the `WHERE` clause.  That would greatly simplify your `Min()` and `Max()` expressions.  But if that still doesn't produce exactly the results you want, show us what it does return and what you want returned instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I must clarify that it was [Datum] in fact in German, there were no problem there. I use Int(Indate) to show date value without time, totally the same as shown on my question above.  I think, I can not use IIF in where since I want to add other shifts.